# Why web server can't decode the request body

Tags: jquery, ajax, web

I have a web app in WeChat, use jQuery ajax to request web server, i found a oddly bug, **sometimes** web server can't decode the ajax request body, use Wireshark to catch the HTTP log, found the reason is that high position swap with low position for every byte, so web server cannot decode it. look the images below:

**correct:**

```
4D 6F 62 69 6C 65 54 65  6C 3D 31 32 33 34 35 36
37 38 39 39 34
```

**false:**

```
D4 F6 26  96 C6 56 45 56 C6 D3 13
23 33 43 53 63 73 83 93  93 43
```

eg. 4D to D4

**Is there anybody can tell me why?**

ajax code:

```
    var options = {
        url: url_signup,
        type: 'post',
        data: data,
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
            $.openTipLayer({content: "注册成功",callback: function(){
                    if (!!url_success_go) {
                        window.location.href = url_success_go;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    MySDK.tools.ajax(options);
```

MySDK.tools.ajax only simplely wrap jquery ajax:

MySDK.tools = {

```
ajax:function(options){
    options = $.extend({needLoading:true }, options);
    var hasLoading=$(".note").filter(":visible").length>0;
    if(!hasLoading && options.needLoading){
        $.openTipLayer({id:"defaultLoading",content: "",closeTime:0,warpClass:"note_loadwarp2",zIndex:3000,isMask:true});
    }
    var success=options.success;
    options.success=function(result){
        if(!hasLoading && options.needLoading){
            $.closeTipLayer({id:"defaultLoading"});
        }
        if(options.sucesssTopFun){
            options.sucesssTopFun();
        }
        if(!result.result){
            if(result.data==-1){
                var url=window.location.href;
                url=encodeURIComponent(url);
                window.location.href=url_login+"&url="+url;
            }
            else{
                $.openTipLayer({content: result.message});
                if(options.resultFalseFun){
                    options.resultFalseFun();
                }
            }
            return;
        }
        if(success){
            success(result);
        }
    }
    var error = options.error;
    options.error = function (xhr) {
        if(!hasLoading && options.needLoading){
            $.closeTipLayer({id: "defaultLoading"});
        }
        var msg =  "server error, code " + xhr.status;
        $.openTipLayer({content: msg});
        if (error) {
            error();
        }
    }
    $.ajax(options);
},
```

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: sample code:    `var options = {
            url: url_signup,
            type: 'post',
            data: data,
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (result) {
                $.openTipLayer({content: "注册成功",callback: function(){
                        if (!!url_success_go) {
                            window.location.href = url_success_go;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
MySDK.tools.ajax(options);`

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28937432/edit) your question to post your codes instead.

Comment: What is MySDK ? Are you referring [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysdk/) ?

Comment: tks .... done it , see